# How do I write case logic using PowerBI?

Tags: powerbi

I have the following case logic that I use in SQL that I need to replicate in PowerBI. I have tried both DAX and Power Query but keep running into errors:

```
CASE
            WHEN LEN((Ltrim(Rtrim(cast([Colum1] as BIGINT ))))) < 11
                THEN CONCAT('5', RIGHT('000000000' +Ltrim(Rtrim(cast([Colum1] as bigint))), 10))
                ELSE Ltrim(Rtrim(cast([Colum1] as BIGINT)))
        END as Account_Number
```

Example Output:

Current
9002682982
2

Desired
59002682982
50000000002

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that Column1 is a text column, you can create a calculated column on your table with the following expression:

```
Account Number = 
 VAR acc = TRIM(table[Column1])
 RETURN IF( LEN(acc) < 11, 
       CONCATENATE("5", RIGHT(CONCATENATE("0000000000", acc),10)),
       acc)
```